# NS Predicate search for "do not have any"

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

I have a simple data model:

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var Name : String = ""
    let Colour = List<ColourItem>()
}

class ColourItem: Object {
    dynamic var colourName = ""
}
```

And I can do `NSPredicate` searches for all `Dog`s, or `Dog`s with a specific colour assigned to them:

```
let importPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN Colour.colourName", colourVar)
let results = realm.objects(Dog).filter(importPredicate)
```

But I am stuck on how to search for just `Dog`s without *any* colour assigned to them. (i.e.: I want to filter for dogs whose `Colour` property is empty).

Any ideas/hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for dogs with an empty `Colour` list like so:

```
let results = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("Colour.@count == 0")
```